# Regexp to Validate an email local-part ORACLE

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to build a regexp for email validation on both parts; local-part and Domain-part, respectively:

**Local-Part**: `^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}` - The maximum total length of the local-part of an email address is 64 octets.

**Domain-Part**: `(([A-Z0-9]{1,63})[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$`

**Regexp** : `^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@(([A-Z0-9]{1,63})[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$`

I'm satisfied with Domain Part. But I need to ensure some rules on Local-part that I'm not being able to achieve, regarding Dots '.'.

Dot's Rule : 
provided that it is not the first or last character unless quoted, and provided also that it does not appear consecutively unless quoted (e.g. John..Doe@example.com is not allowed but "John..Doe"@example.com is allowed).

On my regexp I already guarantee that Dot is not **first** char. I need to check for consecutive Dots (e.g. '..' not allowed but ".." is allowed, and that '.@' must not happen too).

Any help please?

Comment: `([A-Z0-9]{1,63})[A-Z0-9]+` matches an infinite length string

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Thank you Toto. I'll check your sugestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second check that the email does not match any number of unquoted, non-at characters and then two consecutive dots.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         email,
         -- your regular expression
         '^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@(([A-Z0-9]{1,63})[A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$'
       )
AND    NOT REGEXP_LIKE( email, '^[^"@]+\.\.' )
```

However, I feel that you would be better off not using your regular expression (since it does not accept quotes or extended character sets and if you can get it working in Oracle use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)) or, even better, just accepting whatever has been entered and sending a confirmation e-mail to the user as this not-only checks that the e-mail is valid syntactically but also checks that the e-mail exists and that the user wants whatever service you are providing.

---

**Update:**

To use the regular expression in the answer linked above:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, email ) AS
SELECT  1, 'abc@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'abc.def@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'abc..def@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'abc.def.@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, '".abc.."@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'abc.def++yourdomain.com@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, '"with\"quotes\""@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, '""@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, '"\' || CHR(9) || '"@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, '"""@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, '123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.1234567890@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'ABC@example.com' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(
         email,
         '^('
           -- Unquoted local-part
           || '[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*'
           --                               ^^
           --                               Allow a dot but always expect a
           --                               non-dot after it.
           -- Quoted local-part
           || '|"('
             -- Unescaped characters in the quotes
             || '[]' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(8) || CHR(11) || CHR(12) || CHR(14) || '-!#-[^-'||CHR(127)||']'
             -- Escaped characters in the quotes
             || '|\\[' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(9) || CHR(11) || CHR(12) || CHR(14) || '-' || CHR(127) || ']'
             || ')*"'
           || ')'
           -- Match at symbol at end of local-part
           || '@',
           -- Case insensitive
           'i'
       )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | EMAIL                                                                             
> -: | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | abc@example.com                                                                   
>  2 | abc.def@example.com                                                               
>  5 | ".abc.."@example.com                                                              
>  6 | abc.def++yourdomain.com@example.com                                               
>  7 | "with\"quotes\""@example.com                                                      
>  8 | ""@example.com                                                                    
>  9 | "\        "@example.com                                                           
> 11 | 123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.1234567890@example.com
> 12 | ABC@example.com
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37be4c92a95ca7df822e5c3b4e043d30)*

Comment: Many thanks MTO. Forgeting the Quotes; what changes would I have to make, to detect consecutive dots and '. @'?

Comment: I don't think you can make it do consecutive dots and have a 64 character limit on the local part (since Oracle does not support look-ahead/-behind); if you want both then you need two separate checks.

Comment: Thank you MTO. I agree with you. I'll use separate checks. Can you help me please on including in the regexp local-part '^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@' the ability to check for consecutive Dot's and Dot @; both '..' or '.@' they are not allowed. The actual regex only prevents the local-part from starting with Dot as first character.

Comment: @LEOPOLDO As linked in the question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/1509264) has a regular expression and you can extract the local part from it: `^([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@`

Comment: Many thanks. I'm kind of rookie in regexes, and the one above seems to be very complex. Can you tell me witch part of the above regex is checking for consecutive dots and Dot as last character before the '@'? I thank you in advance.

Comment: @LEOPOLDO The regular expression is not checking for the absence of two consecutive dots; its enforcing that if there is a dot then there must be a non-dot character after it in the non-quoted syntax for the local part. Its effectively the same thing just approaching it from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as
  (select 'brucewayne.1981@gmail.com' email from dual
  union all
  select 'clark_kent@gmail.com' email from dual
  union all
  select '1Tonystark.1980@gmail.com' email from dual
  union all
  select 'peter@parker.1989@gmail.com' email from dual
  union all
  select 'ducamanoel2015@gmail..com.br' email from dual
  )
select *
from t
where regexp_like(email,'^\w+(\.\w+)*+@\w+(\.\w+)+$');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is appreciated but a code-only answer is not very useful and in this case I do not see how it answers the question. Please add some explanations of what this code does and how it actually answers the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Filter using below sql-

```html
like '%_@__%.__%'
```